# How to render mini panel in custom template programatically?

Tags: panels

I have a minipanel and I have a custom template. How can I render minipanel in my custom template programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mini Panels are available as blocks. So you'd be rendering it in the same way you render any block programmatically in Drupal 7.

Use

```
$block = module_invoke('panels_mini', 'block_view', 'machine_name_of_mini_panel');
print $block['content'];
```